# How to find the second to last Char occurrence in a linked list recursively?

Tags: java, recursion, singly-linked-list

As a homework assignment I'm suppose to return the position of the second to last occurrence of a letter--to know what letter to check it is passed as a Char type parameter. What I'm searching through is a self-coded linked list. It also has to be done recursively, which I've been struggling to fully understand. Here's what I've worked out so far.

Note: If a letter appears either 0 or 1 time, return -1.

E.g.
     ["ababcdefb"].positionOfSecondToLastOccurrence('b') == 3

```
static class Node {
        public Node (char item, Node next) { this.item = item; this.next = next; }
        public char item;
        public Node next;
    }

Node first;

public int positionOfSecondToLastOccurrence (char letter) {

        if (first == null)
            return -1;

        return positionOfSecondToLastOccurrenceHelper(letter, first, 0);
    }

private int positionOfSecondToLastOccurrenceHelper(char c, Node n, int pos) {

        if (n.next == null)
            return n.item;

        return pos += compare(n.item, positionHelper(c, n.next, pos));

    }

private int compare(char c, int p) {

        int result = 0;

        if (c == p)
            return result += 1;

        return 0;
    }
```

I understand why this isn't working; I'm returning a result of 1 and then comparing it to n.item when going back to the previous function call, which will never be true. What I don't know is how to make this work. Any guidance would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a singly-linked list, which means you can only traverse it in one direction, namely forward, i.e. from the first node to the last node.

The algorithm is then to traverse the list from first node to last node and compare each node's `item` with the item you are searching for. Also you need two variables that will hold the index in the list of both the last (i.e. ultimate) and the second last (i.e. penultimate) occurrences of the item you are searching for. Both these variables should have initial values of -1 (minus one).

When you hit the first occurrence of the searched for item, update the ultimate index variable. When you hit the next occurrence, set the penultimate index to the ultimate index and then update the ultimate index.

Repeat for every subsequent occurrence of the searched for item, i.e. set the penultimate index to the ultimate index and then set the ultimate index to the index of the current node in the list. Hence if the searched for item occurs only once in the list, or does not occur at all, the penultimate index will be -1.

When writing a recursive method, the first thing you need is some condition that will terminate the recursion. If the condition is true, return an appropriate value. If the condition is false, change the method arguments and recall the same method with the modified arguments. The terminating condition in your case is a null node.

Since a list is not an array, you also need to track the index of the current node, so as to be able to return it from your recursive method.

Here is my implementation. I created a `LinkList` class which contains a list of your `Node` class. The `LinkList` class allows me to initially create a linked list. I also added method `toString()` to both `Node` and `LinkList` classes to help visualize what the list looks like. The `main()` method serves as a test of the recursive method. The first invocation of the recursive method uses the first node in the list, whose index is 0 (zero).

```java
public class Penultim {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkList list = new LinkList();
        list.append('a');
        list.append('b');
        list.append('a');
        list.append('b');
        list.append('c');
        list.append('d');
        list.append('e');
        list.append('f');
        list.append('b');
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println(list.getPenultimateOccurrenceIndex('b', list.getHead(), 0, -1, -1));
    }
}

class Node {
    private char item;
    private Node next;

    public Node(char item, Node next) {
        this.item = item;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public char getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return item + "->";
    }
}

class LinkList {
    private Node head;

    public void append(char item) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node(item, null);
        }
        else if (head.getNext() == null) {
            head.setNext(new Node(item, null));
        }
        else {
            Node node = head.getNext();
            while (node != null) {
                if (node.getNext() == null) {
                    node.setNext(new Node(item, null));
                    break;
                }
                node = node.getNext();
            }
        }
    }

    public Node getHead() {
        return head;
    }

    public int getPenultimateOccurrenceIndex(char item,
                                             Node node,
                                             int ndx,
                                             int penultimate,
                                             int ultimate) {
        if (node == null) {
            return penultimate;
        }
        else {
            if (node.getItem() == item) {
                if (ultimate >= 0) {
                    penultimate = ultimate;
                }
                ultimate = ndx;
            }
            return getPenultimateOccurrenceIndex(item,
                                                 node.getNext(),
                                                 ndx + 1,
                                                 penultimate,
                                                 ultimate);
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Node node = head;
        while (node != null) {
            sb.append(node);
            node = node.getNext();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

The output when running the above code is

```
a->b->a->b->c->d->e->f->b->
3
```

Comment: That worked! I understand the logic you've presented here 100%; creating it myself is still very difficult for me, so thanks for providing this. So far in my studies they've only showed us simple recursion problems so I thought recursion shouldn't be as intricate as something like the getPenultimateOccurrenceIndex(). This just showed me it CAN be intricate!

Answer (score 0):

I’d do this in smaller steps. I’d start by writing a `positionOfLastOccurrence(char letter)`. Writing this as a recursive method should teach you some of the technique that you will also need for `positionOfSecondToLastOccurrence()`.

Next much of the challenge is in a good design of the helper method or methods. I think that I’d write a `positionOfLastOccurrenceBeforePosition(int pos, char letter)` that should return the position of the last occurrence of `letter` strictly before position `pos`. So given your example list, `ababcdefb`, `positionOfLastOccurrenceBeforePosition(0, 'b')` would return -1, `positionOfLastOccurrenceBeforePosition(2, 'b')` would yield 1 and `positionOfLastOccurrenceBeforePosition(100, 'b')` would give 8. This method too should be recursive, I believe, since this will the one doing the actual work in the end.

Now finding the second last occurrence is a matter of first finding the last occurrence and then finding the last occurrence before that one.

Comment: What confuses me the most is how to keep track of the number of instances a letter appears when searching recursively, since each instance of the method is just wiped from memory once it's done.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation; knowing how to find the "smaller step" is something I have to work on.

Comment: If you follow my suggestion (which isn’t the only way to solve it), you don’t need to keep track of the number of instances. Happy fighting. :-)